# Program to generate iterations

Tags: c, file, logic, structure

I have set myself a task to code this algorithm, however, since i haven't had a full experience in C, I was hoping there might be an easier method.

Ok, Take 2 numbers, 
    a , b

We take the sum of these and add to the sequence, then add on the second term.

So we get 
    a , b , a+b , b

For the next term, we take the 2nd and 3rd values (Before we did 1st and 2nd) and do it again.

so we now get

```
a , b , a+b , b , a +2b , a+b
```

(continued)       `a+2b , b , a+3b , a+2b , 2a+3b , a+b`

This continues on until whenever, it does not have to have an input.

Basically my algorithm comes as: The next a was the previous b , the Next b is the previous a + the previous b.

However, i cannot code this in c using general methods, since it will work from the appended values given to the sequence, rather than the 1st , 2nd , 3rd values etc.

I was thinking that this could be done instead by writing to a file and scanning line by line for the nth number. However, i think i am way over complicating this.

Is there a way that i can take an nth value from this sequence?

Input: a = 1 , b =1 . Expected output: 1, 1 ,2 ,1 3, 2 , 3 ,1 ,4 3, 5 , 2

Comment: I think you are looking for [arrays](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays).

Comment: @cnicutar Ok, I have no idea what an array is.

Comment: It might not be obvious due to rendering issues but the last word in my comments is a link to a page that will describe what arrays are.

Comment: @cnicutar I see that now, I'll try it with the files first since i'm not so experienced with the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use arrays, it is not difficult and it will be much better than using files. Read some documentation and you should be able to use them in 5min.

An array is just a sequence of things, integers in your case.
You probably can do something like this:

```
int main () {
    int array[MAX];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 1;
    // Print the starting values:
    printf("%d\n%d\n", array[0], array[1]);

    // The loop is controlled by i, increased in steps of 2.
    // j keeps the sequence of 1,2; 2,3; 3,4... used for the sum
    for (int i = 2, j = 0; i < MAX; i+=2, j++) {
        array[i] = array[j] + array[j+1];
        array[i+1] = array[j+1];
        printf("%d\n%d\n", array[i], array[i+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alright, It says that there are conflicting types for "array", what now?

Comment: The previous answer was in pseudo code, so the array wasn't declared. Check the updated one. Also, my answer stores all the values of the sequence in the array, it is similar to use files but more efficient.

If you just want to get the nth value of the sequence, then you are looking for a program like the one @rcgldr provides.

Answer (score 1):

"The next a was the previous b , the Next b is the previous a + the previous b." If you're just trying to get the nth value, you can use the 4 variables you just described (this could be optimized, but might as well code to match the description):

```
int n = 12;
int i;
int preva = 1;
int prevb = 1;
int nexta;
int nextb;
    for(i = 2; i < n; i += 2){
        nexta = prevb;
        nextb = preva + prevb;
        preva = nexta;
        prevb = nextb;
    }
    if(i == n)
        /* output prevb */
    else
        /* output preva */
```