# Iterations of a sequence with files

Tags: c, string, file, structure, sequences

Ok, so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443601/program-to-generate-iterations) I asked how I can simplify a method of creating a certain series in a file. I came to the conclusion that I should use file handling.

Just to make myself clear, this is the algorithm of the sequence I intend to create:

```
_____
1 , 1  Take the 1st and 2nd numbers.

_____
1 , 1 , 2 , 1 Append Their sum, and Append the second value.

    _____
1 , 1 , 2 , 1 Take the 2nd and 3rd numbers

    _____
1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 2 Append Their sum, and Append the second value.

        _____
1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 2 Take the 3rd and 4th numbers

        _____
1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 1 Append Their sum, and Append the second value.
```

This should create the sequence: 1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 4 , 3 , 5 .....

Now, I have created some code in C that should be able to generate this sequence, but somehow does not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x=1;
int y=1;
int z=2;

int DataCount = 1;
FILE *fFs;

struct storeX
{ 
   int defX[16]; 
}stockX[16];  

struct storeY
{ 
   int defY[16]; 
}stockY[16];  

int main()
{
   fFs=fopen("Fibb.txt","w"); //Clears the file.
   fclose(fFs);

   fFs=fopen("Fibb.txt","a");
   fprintf(fFs,"%d\n",x);
   fprintf(fFs,"%d\n",y);

   DataCount = 1;
   do
   {
      z = x+y;
      fprintf(fFs,"%d\n",z);
      fprintf(fFs,"%d\n",y);
      DataCount = DataCount + 1;
      fscanf(fFs,"%16[^\n]%*c", stockX[DataCount].defX);
      fscanf(fFs,"%16[^\n]%*c", stockY[(DataCount+1)].defY);
      x= atoi(stockX[DataCount].defX);
      y= atoi(stockY[(DataCount+1)].defY);
   }
   while(DataCount < 100);

   fclose(fFs);
}
```

I think the problem lies in the scan, but I can't be too sure.

The file output: (going line by line down)

```
1
1
2
1
                                      0
0      
                                      0
0   
                                      0
0   
                                      0
0   
                                      0
0
```

Comment: You opened the file for appending.  If you want to read from it (with scanf), you should open a second filehandle with mode "r".

Comment: @WilliamPursell I actually just facepalmed several times , thank you sir.

Comment: @WhipItOut you can answer your own post, and accept the answer.

Comment: @iharob I'm just fixing the code now, i'll be sure to answer it after.